# AngularJS - Unit Test - Test Controller With Custom Services

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-runner

I have been searching for a couple of hours now for a solution for this but I just can't make it work.
I have a Controller defined as:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('spaSkeleton.parCCP')
        .controller('ParCCPCtrl', function ($scope, $mdToast, AnosLetivosService, UnidadesOrganicasService, CursosService, RelatoriosService, PareceresService) {
    //my code
```

and I want to test this controller, but i have all this Services that I have to inject.
One of the Services looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('sigq.anosLetivos', []);
app.service('AnosLetivosService', function (Restangular) {
    this.getAnosLetivos = function () {
        return Restangular.all("anos-letivos").getList({"sort": "ano_inicio"});
    };
});
```

and in my test file I have this:

```
describe('Parecer Controllers', function(){

    beforeEach(module('spaSkeleton.parCCP'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('namespace.anosLetivos');
        module('namespace.unidadesOrganicas');
        module('namespace.cursos');
        module('namespace.relatorios');
        module('namespace.pareceres');
        module('namespace.landingPage');
    });


    describe('Parecer Ctrl', function(){
        var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $httpBackend.expectGET(...).respond(...);

            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('ParCtrl', {$scope: scope});
        }));

    });

});
```

I would like some help on how to inject these services into the controller so i can test it. I already tried a lot of stuff.
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11 this looks easy but does not work, he doesn't even inject stuff or does he? I know in the tutorial works but I don't know how and why and I can't make it work on my project.

Any help is welcome :D

Answer (score 2):

so I solved my problem, the problem was that the services had a module that i had to inject in the test that i wasn't seeing.

```
describe('Parecer Controllers', function(){

    beforeEach(module('spaSkeleton.parCCP'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('sigq.anosLetivos');
        module('sigq.unidadesOrganicas');
        module('sigq.cursos');
        module('sigq.relatorios');
        module('sigq.pareceres');
        module('restangular');
        module('ngMaterial');
    });

    var $scope;
    var $controller;
    var $mdToast, AnosLetivosService, UnidadesOrganicasService, CursosService, RelatoriosService, PareceresService, Restangular;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$q_, _AnosLetivosService_, _UnidadesOrganicasService_, _CursosService_,
                               _RelatoriosService_, _PareceresService_, _Restangular_, _$mdToast_) {
        $scope = {};
        $mdToast = _$mdToast_;
        Restangular = _Restangular_;
        $controller = _$controller_;
        AnosLetivosService = _AnosLetivosService_;
        UnidadesOrganicasService = _UnidadesOrganicasService_;
        CursosService = _CursosService_;
        RelatoriosService = _RelatoriosService_;
        PareceresService = _PareceresService_;

        $controller('ParCCPCtrl',
            {
                '$scope': $scope,
                'AnosLetivosService': AnosLetivosService,
                'UnidadesOrganicasService': UnidadesOrganicasService,
                'CursosService': CursosService,
                'RelatoriosService': RelatoriosService,
                'PareceresService': PareceresService,
                '$mdToast': $mdToast
            });
    }));

    it('should make Blog menu item active.', function() {
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

so i need all this code to test my controller xD